# How can I make NetBean's autocomplete function more responsive like Xcode?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, autocomplete

I've been an `Xcode` user for quite a while, and I really liked its autocomplete functionality.

Now that I'm working on a Java project, I decided to pick `NetBeans`. I have found that its autocompletion is not as responsive as `Xcode`:

---

If you have

```
int myVariable = 10;
```

And you later type "my", Xcode will suggest `myVariable`. `NetBeans` doesn't suggest anything when you start typing a line.

---

If your object `stream` has two methods `writeBytes` and `writeData`:

And you begin typing

```
stream.writeB
```

Both `Xcode` and `NetBeans` will suggest the `writeBytes`. **BUT** if you later decide that you wanted `writeData` instead, you press the backspace key to delete the `B` and then add a `D`. At this point, with `writeD`, `Xcode` will suggest `writeData`, **but `NetBeans` will stop suggesting anything from the moment you used the backspace key**.

---

The same occurs with Eclipse.

Is there a way to make NetBeans' (or Eclipse's) autocompletion as responsive as `Xcode`?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> then suggestions will displayed. After pressing <kbd>D</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>